# Create a texture background for a view

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

Is there any way we can add or create texture our Xcode 6 project in Swift?

I know how to change the background colors or use rgb's. As an example:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

But how can we add or create textures for background?

Comment: Add an image to your `UIView` or add an image to a `UIImageView` the size of your background. Can you be more clear with what you're attempting to achieve?

Comment: Probably UiColor(patternImage:)

Answer (score 8):

Add an image to your Images.xcassets library. Add it to the view like this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "MyBackgroundImage")!)
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave Batton. So my next question is, in xcode I wanna use iPhone screen size from iPhone 4s to iPhone 6 Plus. So, will I need to create a different images for each each iPhone size or xcode will adjust one image itself to corresponding screen size?

Comment: You need to post that as a new question. I'll watch for it.